# Register daemon controllable by start and stop command in Linux

Tags: linux, configuration, daemon

Many system daemon can be started using start/stop command. I was just curious how start/stop works on Linux system. Say I wrote a daemon executable, how should I configure it so that it can be controlled by start/stop in Linux.

Comment: You may be looking for https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html (and more generally https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/) but that's just one (popular) possibility for daemon management.  Without knowing which distribution you're talking about, we can't be more specific.  (The Linux-based computer I'm typing this on does not _have_ "start" and "stop" commands.)

Answer (score 2):

I make a daemon in linux (ArchLinux) few years ago, and it works every day perfectly.
There are 2 ways to do this. Short way and long way:

**Short Way:**

Create a file in /etc/systemd/system/ called for example mydaemon.service :

**/etc/systemd/system/mydaemon.service**

```
[Unit]
Description=This is my first daemon! - Fernando Pucci
After=network.target

[Service]
User=root
WorkingDirectory=/root
Type=oneshotmc
RemainAfterExit=yes
ExecStart=/bin/echo -e "Daemon started"
ExecStop=/bin/echo -e "Daemon Stopped"

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

This service does nothing but show Daemon Started or Stopped. You can change echoes by the sentences you need.

If you need to run some script, try the Long way:

**Long way**
Create a file in some directory, like root folder or /usr/lib/systemd/scripts called for example

**/root/mydaemon.sh**

```
start() {
    <your start sentences here
    and here>
}   
stop() {
    <your stop sentences here
    and here>
}

case $1 in  
   start|stop) "$1" ;;
esac
```

You must to make it runnable (chmod x)
(And you can execute it with start or stop parameter to test it.)

And as second step, create another file in 
**/usr/lib/systemd/system/mydaemon.service**

```
[Unit]
Description=Second daemon of Fernando Pucci
After=network.target

[Service]
User=root
WorkingDirectory=/root
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=yes
ExecStart=/bin/bash -c '/root/mydaemon.sh start'
ExecStart=/bin/echo -e "MyDaemon Started"
ExecStop=/bin/bash -c '/root/mydaemon.sh stop'
ExecStop=/bin/echo -e "MyDaemon Stopped"

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

**Starting and Stopping**

```
systemctl start mydaemon
systemctl stop mydaemon
systemctl status mydaemon
systemctl enable mydaemon
systemctl disable mydaemon
```

You (and someone) can send me a private msg for help about that.